# Drool queries have unstable behavior when used in LHS

Tags: drools

Is it normal for a rule match not to be canceled if the condition is in a query and it contains a fact inserted after that rule got triggered once? Or is this some bug in drools 7.16?

Here are some simplified examples of what I'm trying to do.

This works the same every time, if there are three objects Fact("chosenFact") then the rule is triggered once:

```
rule "Rule"
when
    Fact(name == "chosenFact")
    not InsertedFact(name == "inserted_chosenFact")
then
    insert(new InsertedFact("inserted_chosenFact"));
end
```

This on the other hand is triggered once, twice or three times:

```
query checkFact(String expectedName)
    Fact(name == expectedName)
    and
    not InsertedFact(name == "inserted_chosenFact")
end

rule "Rule" 
when
    checkFact("chosenFact";)
then
    insert(new InsertedFact("inserted_chosenFact"));
end
```

The logs show that sometimes the match created is cancelled, but sometimes it is not.

Comment: Hopefully the first one, which always succeeds, is the idiomatic one, right?! Do you really have to make the second way work?

Comment: @uprego for the simpler cases yes, but there are some more complex repetitive rules that I wanted to extract the duplication from.  The only solution I could think of is to leave the condition with InsertedFact out of the query, that works as well.

Comment: `"inserted_chosenFact"` has to be parameter of `query checkFact(...)`, doesnt'it?

Comment: @uprego yeah, it's a string to identify the object inserted by that rule.

Comment: I wonder if the minimum reproducible example is completely minimum. I would think some of those identifying strings can be removed, or at least replaced for some others only present in consequents. But I've been away of Drools too long to try. I would try other versions of Drools and ask their mailing list or equivalent troubleshooting system.

Comment: I see a semicolon in `checkFact("chosenFact";)`, is that a typo? (Haven't used Drools for a while).

Comment: Does using `.equals(...)` make any effective difference? (I know, it's old thing. But talking about Java, string comparison using `.equals(...)` is more base line than using `==`).

Comment: @uprego It doesn't work without the semicolon. I've tried the same queries with other facts and even the InsertedFact, the problem is just when new facts are inserted into the working memory, it's as if the query is done on the initial state of of the working memory. This happens on older versions as well.

Comment: Hi @CookieMonster, have you had a chance to fix this ? I'm witnessing something similar in my app - query doesn't trigger the rules as expected, but copying the query in the LHS directly works...

Comment: hey @MarcGhorayeb, I changed the rules completely and stopped using functions in the LHS because I noticed that they don't take into consideration how the Working Memory changes.